# Continuous row in phymyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to get continuous row automatically everytime i click next in my application, the row get next record, for example from A1 to A2, from A2 to A3 and so on.

here's my table structure:

```
|id|code 
|1 | A1
|2 | A2
|3 | A3
|4 | A4
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `code` column is UNIQUE in the table, and assuming that we are returning rows in `code` order,  we can just save the `code` value of the current row in the web page returned that is sent to the user/browser

```
<input type="hidden" name="code_current" value="A2"/>
```

(as part of the form that gets submitted when the "next" button is clicked)

Then in the PHP script that handles the submit of the form, we extract the value from the form, e.g.

```
$code_prev = $_POST['code_current']
```

and use that value in the execution of the SQL that gets the "next" row. That would be a row with a `code` value greater than the previous value. For example:

```
$sql = 'SELECT t.id
             , t.code
          FROM mytable t
         WHERE t.code > ?
         ORDER BY t.code
         LIMIT 1';
```

Assuming we've configured the PDO connection `$dbh` to throw an exception when an error is detected...

```
  $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $sth->execute($code_prev);
```

And we include the value of `code` column (of the row we retrieved from the database) in a hidden input of the web page, on the form that gets returned when the user clicks "next", ...

```
  if( $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {

      echo '<input type="hidden" name="code_current" value="' 
         . htmlspecialchars( $row['code'] )
         . '"/>';

  }
```

---

This assumes that the rows are being returned in order by `code` value.  If they are being returned in `id` order instead, then use the `id` column in place of `code`.

If `code` is not unique, that is, if there are (or can be) multiple rows with the same `code` value, we could use both `code` and `id` values.

The condition in the WHERE clause would be something like this:

```
 WHERE t.code >= ? 
   AND (t.code > ? OR t.id > ? )
```

such that if the previous row we pulled was code=A2 id=2, the query to get the "next" row would be equivalent to this:

```
WHERE t.code >= 'A2'
  AND ( t.code > 'A2' OR t.id > 2 )
```

Comment: sorry, but i'm using java not php :(

Comment: @HenryWilson: there's no `Java` tag on the question, no mention of `Java` or `JDBC` in the question. Not a single line of example code. 
 The pattern in this answer is the same whether the application is written in Perl/CGI,PHP, or Java.